# Populate HTML with JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

Having a bit of trouble. The goal is to populate an HTML page with JSON data that has been requested in JavaScript. I have successfully displayed the http request code and status in the document. However, I am unable to successfully display data that is in the JSON. I'm not sure if line 7 of the JS is correct because I made it from an example. Also in the JS, line 13, is the line that I cannot get working. (I would like ONLY to use JavaScript and HTML - no AJAX, JQUERY, etc.)
Any suggestions would be helpful, I haven't found anything on this site so far that is similar to my issue.

BELOW IS THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="NEO.js"></script>
<title>NEO</title>
</head>
<body onload="getData()">
<p id="xhrStatus">text</p>
<p id="xhrText">text1</p>
<p id="neoName">name</p>
</body>
</html>
```

BELOW IS THE JS

```
function getData()
{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "ADDRESS LEFT BLANK INTENTIONALLY FOR STACKOVERFLOW", false);
xhr.send(null)
var responseData = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
//the line above is base off of an example. Not sure if it's correct

document.getElementById("xhrStatus").innerHTML = xhr.status;
document.getElementById("xhrText").innerHTML = xhr.statusText;

//Having trouble with line below. Not grabbing data correctly.
var neoName = responseData.near_earth_objects.2017-03-15[0];
document.getElementById("neoName").innerHTML = neoName;
}
```

BELOW IS THE JSON (from placing call in address bar)

```
{
  "links": {
    "next": "ADDRESS LEFT OUT INTENTIONALLY",
    "prev": "ADDRESS LEFT OUT INTENTIONALLY",
    "self": "ADDRESS LEFT OUT INTENTIONALLY"
  },
  "element_count": 5,
  "near_earth_objects": {
    "2017-03-15": [
      {
        "links": {
          "self": "ADDRESS LEFT OUT INTENTIONALLY"
        },
        "neo_reference_id": "2011398",
        "name": "11398 (1998 YP11)",
        "nasa_jpl_url": "ADDRESS LEFT OUT INTENTIONALLY",
        "absolute_magnitude_h": 16.3,
        "estimated_diameter": {
          "kilometers": {
            "estimated_diameter_min": 1.4606796427,
            "estimated_diameter_max": 3.2661789745
          },
          "meters": {
            "estimated_diameter_min": 1460.6796427136,
            "estimated_diameter_max": 3266.1789744576
          },
          "miles": {
            "estimated_diameter_min": 0.9076239703,
            "estimated_diameter_max": 2.0295088955
          },
          "feet": {
            "estimated_diameter_min": 4792.2561990004,
            "estimated_diameter_max": 10715.8106265596
          }
        },
        "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": false,
        "close_approach_data": [
          {
            "close_approach_date": "2017-03-15",
            "epoch_date_close_approach": 1489561200000,
            "relative_velocity": {
              "kilometers_per_second": "7.6545148105",
              "kilometers_per_hour": "27556.2533179201",
              "miles_per_hour": "17122.384179682"
            },
            "miss_distance": {
              "astronomical": "0.2788205228",
              "lunar": "108.4611816406",
              "kilometers": "41710956",
              "miles": "25917986"
            },
            "orbiting_body": "Earth"
          }
        ],
        "orbital_data": {
          "orbit_id": "232",
          "orbit_determination_date": "2017-03-14 06:21:59",
          "orbit_uncertainty": "0",
          "minimum_orbit_intersection": ".202697",
          "jupiter_tisserand_invariant": "4.048",
          "epoch_osculation": "2457800.5",
          "eccentricity": ".3889800628971847",
          "semi_major_axis": "1.720520012229252",
          "inclination": "15.02606696200692",
          "ascending_node_longitude": "144.8173241683082",
          "orbital_period": "824.3051621591791",
          "perihelion_distance": "1.051272029656453",
          "perihelion_argument": "74.64055539736296",
          "aphelion_distance": "2.389767994802052",
          "perihelion_time": "2457881.692298597634",
          "mean_anomaly": "324.5407685928043",
          "mean_motion": ".4367314636936381",
          "equinox": "J2000"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Try: `responseData.near_earth_objects.['2017-03-15'][0];` instead. I don't believe you can use dot notation on that key.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use - without being in a string 
AND you're setting the inner html to a javascript object not a string

try this instead

```
var neoName = responseData.near_earth_objects["2017-03-15"][0].neo_reference_id;
```

if you want to display the whole object you could use `stringify()`

```
var neoName = JSON.stringify(responseData.near_earth_objects["2017-03-15"][0]);
```